# Problem of key binding, how to keep focus on app so the shortcut works

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, focus, vlc

I'm a beginner so bear with me :)
I searched on the forum but no luck until now, here is the situation:

- I created an app using the library **Tkinter**.
- You fill in a youtube URL in an input and the app launch VLC to play it.
- Key bindings are here to manipulate the player (pause, play, next, etc).

**Problem :** Key bindings do nothing. I get the feeling that it's a focus problem.
**my config :** python 3.6, Ubuntu 20.10


The binding works but since the vlc player is launched, I get the feelin that it is focused on the player and not the app. I tried to get the focus back on the app but it does not work.

Can you help me with this one?

**Here is a synthetic version of my code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import pafy
import vlc

# -- GLOBAL --#
myApp = None
mediaPlayer = None


def createInterface():
    idInput = Entry(myApp)
    idInput.pack()
    launch_button = Button(myApp, text='OK')
    launch_button['command'] = lambda myinput=idInput: ValidateForm(myinput)
    launch_button.pack()
    
def launchVideo(myinput):
    vidURL = myinput.get()
    
    # launch VLC player with URL
    video = pafy.new(vidURL)
    best = video.getbest()
    mediaPlayer = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
    mediaPlayer.play()
    
    #init keyboard shortcuts
    setShortcuts()
    

def setShortcuts():
    myApp.bind( "<p>", printPause() )

def printPause():
    print('paused')


#--- MAIN ---#
myApp = Tk()
myApp.lift()
myApp.mainloop()
```